# Cards with dependent 3 rows (same height of all 3 rows)

Tags: angular, row, height

I want to create a shop where I'll have tile with item divided for 3 rows.

1 row - title
2 row - picture
3 row - add to cart button / quantity to choose / multiple dropdowns displayed conditionally / certain info about item and many more

1 row might be different in height depending on title of item.
3 row might be different in height depending on content.

Is there a way to make all rows same height and dependent on each other?

so if many items are displayed, all rows need to be always in same height based on the highest row.

So:

Item 6 - highest 1 row = all the 1 rows have to adapt to this height
Item 9 - highest 2 row = all the 2 rows have to adapt to this height

etc.

I'm using angular and bootstrap - I thought that it might be resolved by card group but I couldn't find a way...

Comment: Could you please share code snippet where you are trying to achieve this, stackblitz would be great as others can play with it and help you quickly

Answer (score 0):

Using classes for grid and overriding some of the CSS rules you can have equal heights for all cards for all rows.

Try the below code

```html
<div class="cards-container grid">
    <div class="card">...</div>
    ...
</div
```

```css
.cards-container.grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.cards-container.grid .card {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="cards-container grid">
  <div class="card">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content. Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.Some quick example text to build on the card title and make</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="180" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>

    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy makes the cards with the same height, but not if you want to makes all the cards with the same height of a title.

You can always use a template reference variable for all the titles, get all of them using ViewChildren , calculate the maxHeight and apply this heigth to all of them.

Well it's more easy than looks like, if your cards are, e.g.

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
         <!--see the template reference variable #title-->
        <h5 #title class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You get all of then using viewChildren

```
  @ViewChildren('title') titles!:QueryList<ElementRef>
```

Then, in ngAfterViewInit

```
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    const maxHeight=this.titles.toArray().reduce((a:number,b:ElementRef)=>
                  a<b.nativeElement.offsetHeight?
                        b.nativeElement.offsetHeight:a,0)
    this.titles.forEach(x=>x.nativeElement.style.height=maxHeight+'px')
  }
```

You can also, listen to window.resize and do it

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(startWith(null))
      .subscribe((_) => {
        this.titles.forEach((x) => (x.nativeElement.style.height = null));
        setTimeout(() => {
          const maxHeight = this.titles
            .toArray()
            .reduce(
              (a: number, b: ElementRef) =>
                a < b.nativeElement.offsetHeight
                  ? b.nativeElement.offsetHeight
                  : a,
              0
            );
          this.titles.forEach(
            (x) => (x.nativeElement.style.height = maxHeight + 'px')
          );
        });
      });
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nxpvq7?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css)